# SQL Server LinkedServer Informix

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, informix

I'm having a hell of a time trying to create a linked server to Informix from SSMS. I can't find anything online that is helping me resolve the problem. I have downloaded the Informix Driver, have successful connectivity with the System DSN, successfully tested pulling data use SquirrelSQL and ConnectTestDemo, but when I go to create the Linked Server from SSMS I receive the following error:

> "Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider Ifxoledbc
>   for linked server 'myServerName'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 7303)"

In the Provider properties I have checked Allow Inprocess for Ifxoledbc. I have also disabled the Firewall to rule out any port blocking.

I'm banging my head against the keyboard and any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Now that you have ODBC working the next step is to get a UDL working. Here's a link for SQL Server - try it for your Informix server. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/farukcelik/archive/2007/12/31/basics-first-udl-test.aspx. If you get it working, open the UDL in notepad and observe the connection string. Also note that a linked server connection occurs from your SQL Server - make sure that the driver is installed on your SQL Server. Linked servers are always difficult to get working.

Comment: Also make sure that it's not a 32-bit vs. 64-bit ODBC driver issue.